# How can I generate transcript from my video with timestamps in json foment

Tags: json, github, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, transcription

I want to show my video transcript and high lite the text in real time like Youtube. 
 I want some suggestion on how can I get file of transcript with timestamps in Json format. 
I get the react tool that accept the video and its transcript data and highlight the text in on real time. Please provide solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sadly I doubt that someone wil come up with a complete solution for you, please ask more specific questions. Also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here, but you might want to pay a visit to [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where this question might be on-topic.